# Probability/ statistics bracket notation?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say $X(t)$ is a random variable for each $t \in \mathbb R$. In various papers I've seen the notation

$$\langle X(t') X(t'+t)\rangle = C(t)$$

where $C(t)$ is referred to as the correlation function,

$$\langle X(t) X(t)\rangle = C(0) \equiv M^2$$
where $M$ is referred to as the typical magnitude, and

$$\langle f(X(t))\rangle$$

(where $f$ is some function, say $\exp(\int X(t) dt)$) referred to as an "ensemble average."

What does the bracket notation $\langle \rangle$ mean? How is it consistent? Could you direct me to a book/ source that explains this?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it's used to denote the expectation operator (with the assumption that your variables have been centered to have mean $0$):

$$ \langle X,Y\rangle \equiv \int xy dP(x,y)dxdy$$

See article [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExpectationValue.html) (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExpectationValue.html)